# Where are Bilhah and Zilpa buried?

Tags: geography, funeral-burial-levaya, imahot-matriarch-mothers

Where are Bilhah and Zilpa buried?

Comment: Where are Bilhah and Zilpah buried?

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87382

Answer (score 6):

There's a place in Tiberias that is supposed to be the common gravesite of several prominent women from Tanach; a sign there lists Bilhah, Zilpah, Yocheved, Tzipporah, Elisheva, and Avigayil. I have no idea of the provenance of this tradition.

Some pictures, and directions, are [here](http://www.mytzadik.com/tadik.asp?kever_id=94&safaid=6).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_of_the_Matriarchs

Comment: Some of these are easier to swallow than others. Avigayil is certainly possible as King David could have had her buried in Tiberias (though why I don't know). Bilhah and Zilpah most likely died in Israel (Genesis 46 sounds like they didn't come down to Egypt), but hadn't they been living in the South part of the country, not anywhere near Tiberias? Yocheved was born and presumably died in Egypt. Tzipporah ("the missing matriarch") ... did she outlive Moshe and make it into Israel? I don't think we know. Elisheva -- see notes on Tzipporah.

Comment: In general it's a big question what it means when various places in the north of Eretz Yisrael are identified as the kevarim of famous tzaddikim or tzidkaniyos - especially when those seem to contradict information given elsewhere. For example, II Chron. 24:16 says that Yehoyada Kohen Gadol was buried in Jerusalem, but there's a grave in Tzfas shown as his (and I believe it was identified as such by the Arizal). One suggestion I've seen is that many or most of these are cenotaphs - memorials to these people, but not their actual burial places.

Comment: According to at least one opinion though, Bilhah came down to Egypt though as she was still alive at the time, thus fulfilling the "moon" part of Joseph's dream. Maybe she was buried in Egypt.

Comment: @CashCow Do you happen to know the source for this opinion?