# When did Bliha and Zilpah die?

Tags: midrash, pentateuch-chumash, imahot-matriarch-mothers

I heard that Seder Olam Rabbah writes that both Rachel and Leah had already passed away by the time of twenty two years after Yaakov married them. We wanted to know if there are any sources when Bilha and Zilpah passed away. Thank you for your help

Comment: Ramban says they died before yaakov went down to mitzraim otherwise they would have been mentioned. I'm pretty sure the Tanchuma mentions the brothers in Egypt asking Bilha's advise how to deal with Yosef after Yaakov passed away.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6656